# How can I put my own code in a wordpress page?

Tags: javascript, code

How can I put my own code in a wordpress page?

This happens when I tried to
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: There should be an option to add a "Code" or "HTML" block to the page, but even if you did that you'd be using it wrong. Your theme already outputs the `html` and `head` elements, as well as styles. The WordPress post/page editor is *not* an HTML editor. If you have highly specific requirements, you might need to create your own template or theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can make wordpress single page template and put your own code and assign this template to your page
[wordpress templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Comment: this is the perfect solution because the editor will add header and footer but in the template you can make your own code and assign your template to this page

Comment: how can I make a single page template? the option only shows default template

Comment: add template file to your themes file and put this header 
* Template Name: Full Width Page

Comment: sorry but I can't still get it

Comment: did you make template file in your theme ?

Comment: if not you can follow steps in   https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the native [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) feature in Wordpress.

Simply create a new file under your parent/child theme. ex. my-template.php.
This file has to start with a PHP comment that defines the template name like this:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: My Cool Template */
    echo "My custom page template!";
```

After you save and upload the file, you'll find the template in editing page under **Page Attributes** box:

[image]

Note that in most cases you just want to add or modify something in the main template and don't want to lose the whole design. In this case I recommend you copy the code of page.php file in your theme to the new template file you created, and just add you modifications to it. If page.php doesn't exist, just use index.php instead.

Comment: how can I create a new file under your parent/child theme?

Comment: Using FTP, locate the directory of your installation then go to wp-content/themes and find the directory of your theme.

Comment: yeah it works. but how can I use my own code to the page?

Comment: Of course you can. Just replace the `echo` line in my code above and keep the comment at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Update your question with the code you're trying with so we can help you. Did you close the PHP code section with `?>` ?

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, mark the answer as accepted so people know you don't need further help!